# url contains special characters

Tags: java, url

I am trying to open a file on a remote server but i am unable to do because the url contains special character(#).
So the url will contains %23 instead # character

There is the code:

```
try {

            URL fichierPropertiesPath = getClass().getResource(DAOFactory.FICHIER_PROPERTIES); // url is like /usr/var/tomcat/project#file/dao.properties

            InputStream fichierProperties = fichierPropertiesPath.openStream();
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(fichierProperties);
            props.replace("client", client);

            fichierProperties.close();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fichierPropertiesPath.getFile());

            props.store(out, null);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How to force the URL to keep the special character ?

Thank you very much

Comment: You need a url decoder. Where are you getting your url from? If it's a library then there's a possibility there's a url decoder in the library.

Comment: It is a bad idea in whatever situation to write into your running classpath. This looks like an XY problem. What is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: (apart from the problem mentioned above, the handling of I/O resources is poor, at best)

Comment: @sisyphus. I am getting the url from the classpath. Can you suggest me a good url decoder plz ? thx

Comment: @fge You are right but i am developping an application which run on local system(windows) and remote system(linux) so i need a common path where store properties file for both environment . Is it a bad manner ? I just want to have an url without special characters . In local it's working fine but in remote system , there is a # in the url which is translated by %23 bu the URL class.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Parallel deployement in tomcat8 add use ## in the war file name so I get the same issue to read my properties files